# Tanks on the Moon

Tags: science-based, weapons

How practical would it be to use tanks on the moon (or any low-gravity airless body)? Would they provide any practical advantage over orbital strikes or suborbital railgun bombardment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tank is a *direct fire* weapon system which carries its own sensors. Asking about tanks vs. suborbital strikes is comparable to asking about tanks vs. artillery today.

Yes, a laser-guided [copperhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M712_Copperhead) round can ruin a tank's day. But first you have to get a grunt with a laser designator into position, and then that infantryman must communicate with the artillery, the artillery has a long flight time, etc. In a high-intensity war, you can't count on having a drone with a designator overhead.

On an airless moon, and presumably in the future, that soldier with a laser designator might be replaced by a small robotic rover. But the principle still applies — if your sensor platform must get into position first and then call for fire, time is lost. There won't be treelines to hide, so the sensor platform might stand out more. Can it survive long enough?

I think if you *want* tanks in your story, you can have them.

Comment: What about geostationary satellites as targeting platforms?

Comment: @DOS4004, what makes you think that they will survive the first minutes of conflict? I was assuming two peer competitors, not a superpower making an intervention.

Comment: Satellites need not be undefended, so they could survive longer than a few minutes. Also, shells can be completely automated, and do not need to have laser guidance.

Comment: I was originally thinking of tanks as an alternative to free-fall crafts, since they have ground contact, they can dodge practically forever, while satellites and hoppers are limited by propellant.

Comment: @DOS4004, what would defend the sats? Adding defenses and armor makes them bigger, so they become a more lucrative target. They cannot hide.

Comment: I suppose that it depends on the advantages of satellites (can see a large portion of the moon) against the lower (?) cost of tanks and continual dodging.

Comment: But tanks cannot hide from sats, as there is no atmosphere or cover

Comment: @DOS4004 geostationary satellites won’t do any good on the **moon**.  Did you mean the analogous situation that keeps station over a point on the lunar equator?  Think about it: 28 day orbit around the moon?  That’s what the Earth does!

Comment: @DOS4004 cover might be an option for tanks, we already use smokescreens for cover and a large scale smokescreen / dust cloud might be possible on the moon as well. On the other hand, the sattelites can't hide from anything nor dodge; and for the *moon* it seems quite feasible to design a small, cheap, mobile "extreme-AA" cannon or missile that can hit them, as there's much lower escape velocity and no atmosphere to slow down extremely fast projectiles.

Comment: the problem with any such tank is that even with smokescreens/dust clouds, if it is manned, it will stand out in IR like a blowtorch. If there is [no stealth in space](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacewardetect.php#id--Strategic_Combat_Sensors--There_Ain't_No_Stealth_In_Space), is stealth still possible on the moon?

Comment: @DOS4004, stealth on the moon will be *easier* than stealth in space. There is background clutter to hide, shadows and ridges, possibly the ground as a heat sink, while the sat has no such cover. If the sat has a line of sight to the tank, the tank has a line of sight to the sat. Except that the sat hangs in the sky.